# React Mathquill command to make readOnly

Tags: reactjs, static, readonly, mathquill

I have created a number of MathQuill fields using React for MathQuill. After typing into fieldA and moving on to fieldB, I want fieldA to become readOnly upon .onFocus() in fieldB.

I am using [React MathQuill](https://libraries.io/github/viktorstrate/react-mathquill) as my reference. I am guessing that there might be a way to use the .config() method to make fieldA read only or convert it into a static MathQuill element. But I haven't been able to figure out how. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MathQuill does not have an official way to make a MathField read only, but you can achieve it by disabling the underlying HTML textarea with the [disabled](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_disabled.asp) attribute.

See the following example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-wing-bk1yj

Comment: Thanks, @viktorstrate this is perfect for my needs!

Comment: For others having the same question: You could use the `mathquillDidMount` prop from react-mathquills' API. The element is accesible via the .`el()` method. http://docs.mathquill.com/en/latest/Api_Methods/#el

Answer (score 0):

The `substituteTextarea` field did the trick for me:

```
<EditableMathField
    config={{
        substituteTextarea: () => {
            const textarea = document.createElement('textarea')
            textarea.disabled = disabled
            return textarea
        },
    }}
/>
```